# Sending delete action as POST request

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a datagrid with bulk actions to delete as well as single delete.

Here is the snapshot of my datagrid:

[image]

my datagrid is as follow :

```
 <form method="post" action="">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkIds[]"/></td>
         <td>user</td><td><a href="user/delete/1"><img src="delete.png"/></a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
```

I can submit data as post when using bulk action delete. Currently for single delete using the delete button action as you can see in the Action column, i am just putting hyperlink or sending it as GET request. As i came to know, the delete action should use POST or DELETE to avoid web crawlers accidentally deleting my data. I thought of a solution to send it as POST action as follow:

```
  <form method="post" action="user/delete/1" id="form_id_1"></form><a href="#" onclick="//submit form"><img src="delete.png"/></a>
```

Problem is that this form tag will be inside my parent form tag and it violates html standards since form tag cannot be inside another form tag

How can I send post request for single delete action here ? Any logic please?

Comment: Do you want a pure php/html solution or a js solution (e.g. `jQuery.post()`)?

Comment: using `jQuery` it can be solved very easily,are you using `jQuery` in your project.

Comment: @sonam set a hidden input area with value and then post the data

Comment: yes i am using jquery, does jquery.post() send an ajax request, but i dont want to send ajax request to delete

Comment: Without using AJAX to post that data, you will be stuck using `get` for it to maintain valid HTML and keeping the bulk delete option available.

Comment: @BasicBridge i thought of that, i would have form inside another form which is not supported or according to rules of html,

Comment: On a side note - if web-crawlers have access to delete your data in such a way that you don't have any validation on the server to verify that a user is logged in etc, you have bigger issues than this.

Comment: i have user authentication validation. usually i used get request to delete  but while i was learning cakephp, cakephp used post request to do this. so i thought of making it as good practice

Comment: If you have validation that whomever is logged in has the ability to use the 'delete' action, using `get` or `post` won't make too large a difference.  Doing actions you do typically want to use `post`, and only use `get` for requesting information.  However, you still have to produce valid HTML - and if you don't want to use JQuery for the action, you will be stuck with a `get` request for the delete.  However, with server-side validation, you should be fine.

Comment: i have seen this been done in phpmyadmin

Comment: If you change them to submit actions and the values of the buttons to some form you can interpret on the server, you can do it that way.  From there, you'd have to modify the class of the buttons to look how you want them to.

Comment: Another option would be to use `onclick` on those `a herf`'s to assign a hidden value a single ID and then submit the form.  Server-side would check the hidden value and delete based upon that instead of the bulk action that typically happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkIds[]"/></td>
         <td>user</td><td><input type="submit" class="sdelete" name="sdelete" value="<?= $ID; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
```

From there, you would use css to modify how the `.sdelete` looks, and in PHP you can get the single delete by:

```
if(isset($_POST['sdelete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['sdelete'];
    //use $id to delete a single entry from DB, and then produce new output
}
```

And that should work flawlessly. ^^

Comment: great and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add another form. Just add another submit button. Use the same form handler, and have it check to see if any of the "delete me" submit buttons are in `$_POST` (which will only happen if they are clicked).

You'll have to use POST for all your actions though.

Answer (score 0):

I came of with a solution as below . please correct me if i m doing it wrong

```
  <form method="post">
  <table>
  // datagrid
  <a href="delete" data="4"><img src="delete.png"/></a>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/>

  // to distinguish between single delete and bulk delete
  <input type="hidden" name="single_delete" value="" id="single_delete_flag"/>
  </form>

  //js
  //onclick handler for anchor action delete:
  $("#id").attr("value",$(this).attr("data"));
  $("#single_delete_flag").attr("value","1");
  $("form").submit();


  //delete.php
  check if request if post
  check if single_delete is 1, then single delete
  else if check bulk delete
```

Comment: you'd have to put the `onclick` handler with the `a`.  But you really want to keep it all in one form and the change a hidden value to do it that way, you'd also want to assign the id of the single item, which doesn't appear to be done in your answer.

Comment: You would want to change `$("#single_delete_flag").attr("value","1");` and then have `"1"` be the actual ID value.   Without passing the ID, you'll never know which entry the 'user' wanted to delete.  I posted a pure HTML/CSS answer that may help. ^^